# How do I know if a telegram user joined my channel?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I am writing a C# desktop app.in this app I write a telegram Id of a user and it says that user is member of the channel or not. my bot is admin of the channel.

I use telegram.bot v9 nugget and searched about this issue all day.

I tried using GetChatMembersCountAsync() in v13 and a lot of other methods but didn't work.

```
    static private Api bot = new Api("Token");
    long id;
    string channel="@ChannelName";

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        id = long.Parse(textBox7.Text);
        if (IsMember(id,channel))
            MessageBox.Show("This user is member of channel");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("This user is not a member of channel");

    }

    private bool IsMember(long id,string channelName)
    {
        //??????????????
    }
```

Is there a method for a telegram bot access to list of members of a channel? what should I write in the IsMember() method?

Thank you very much

---

This problem solved by updating telegram.bot nugget to v10 and using GetChatMemberAsync method.

```
    private bool IsMember(long id,string channelName)  
    {  
        var t = bot.GetChatMemberAsync(channelName, id);
            if (t.Result.Status.ToString().Length > 25)
                return false;
            return true;
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) method to do that, see following example.

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP was asking for... but questions like this make me wonder why we have manuals, so ... anything goes, I guess?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to [Telegram Bot API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) currently there is no method available for bots to get a list of chat members (channel or group).
Here is a small trick:
You can check the updates (messages) came from Telegram to your webhook, if `new_chat_members` field has a value and the `chat_id` field indicates that it's from your channel, then you may save the information about the recent users who joined your channel.