# How do I know if a telegram user joined my channel using telegram bot api?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Please take a look at [this link](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/blob/master/src/Telegram.Bot/TelegramBotClient.cs) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542451/how-do-i-know-if-a-telegram-user-joined-my-channel).
Based on second link i did this :

```
public static class Program {
    private static readonly TelegramBotClient Bot = new TelegramBotClient("My Token");

    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        var me = Bot.GetMeAsync().Result;
        Console.Title = me.Username;

        Bot.OnMessage += BotOnMessageReceived;
        Bot.OnMessageEdited += BotOnMessageReceived;
        Bot.OnCallbackQuery += BotOnCallbackQueryReceived;
        Bot.OnInlineQuery += BotOnInlineQueryReceived;
        Bot.OnInlineResultChosen += BotOnChosenInlineResultReceived;
        Bot.OnReceiveError += BotOnReceiveError;

        Bot.StartReceiving(Array.Empty < UpdateType > ());
        Console.WriteLine($ "Start listening for @{me.Username}");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Bot.StopReceiving();
    }

    private static async void BotOnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs) {
        var message = messageEventArgs.Message;

        if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.Text) return;

        bool is_member_of_channel = Is_Member_Of_Channel("@Channel_Name", message.From.Id);
    }

    private static bool Is_Member_Of_Channel(string channel_name, int user_id) {
        var t = Bot.GetChatMemberAsync(channel_name, user_id);
        if (t.Result.Status.ToString().Length > 25) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

But i have this error :

> An exception of type
>   'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not
>   handled in user code
>
> Additional information: One or more errors occurred.

What is the problem & how can i fix it?

What is channel name?

Did i do right about channel name?

`GetChatMemberAsync()` tells channel name is `ChatId`, How can i get `ChatId` of my channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem & how can i fix it?

> Your bot should be add as `administrator` in the goal channel.
>      Goal
>   channel should be `public`.

What is channel name?

> The correct is : `@Channel_Name`

Did i do right about channel name?

> Yes,

Here is the correct method :

```
private static bool Is_Member_Of_Channel(string channel_name, int user_id)
{
    //Status Values
    //Creator
    //Member
    //Left
    var t = Bot.GetChatMemberAsync(channel_name, user_id);
    if (t.Result.Status.ToString() == "Left")
        return false;
    return true;
}
```